# How do I dynamically assign a variable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to highlight a table header depending on a variable's name passed in via the params.

In the controller I have:

```
case sort
    when 'grade'
        @sort_by_grade = 'highlight'
    when 'student_name'
        @sort_by_student_name = 'highlight'
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? For instance, something like:

```
"sort_by_#{sort}" = 'highlight'
```

My table headers code are something like this in Haml:

```
%th{:class => @sort_by_grade}
```

Comment: What code are you using in the view? Do you have a CSS class called "highlight"?

Comment: And is the sort variable coming from something like params[:sort]?

Comment: I'd say a more elegant approach would be to use a view helper. Could you output the code for your table headers?

Comment: Yes, I do have a css class for highlight. The above code works, since in the view the th tag will have the class like the variable name. I just wish I could use meta programming to dynamically select which @sort_by variable I should use

Comment: Show us the code for the table headers. The highlight should be managed entirely from within the view and helpers. Not the controller.

Comment: The 'metaprogramming' method you're searching for: `instance_variable_set("@sort_by_#{sort}", "highlight")`, but I'd advise against it. If you do use that method be sure that `params[:sort]` variable is properly cleansed.

Comment: when you say cleansed, what does it mean? someone could inject code in it somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't advise constructing dynamic variables based on user input for any reason, it is asking for trouble and is bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct answer to your question (not best practice):

```
instance_variable_set :"@sort_by_#{sort}", 'highlight'
```

But really, using a hash or other better data structure is a better answer.

Comment: guess that's the answer I was originally looking for, but I do agree that the next answer is better... thanks Damien

Comment: @gaudi_br to be fair, I've covered both in my answer, and I already answered in the comments. Anyway, I sincerely suggest you avoid using the above technique and use a view helper. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

As I detailed in the comments, which is hacky and bad practice:

`instance_variable_set("@sort_by_#{sort}", "highlight")`

Personally, I wouldn't manage the highlight logic from within the controller. Extract it into a view helper or put the logic directly in the view:

```
%th{class: ('highlight' if params[:sort] == 'grade')}
```

Or, using a view helper:

#### application_helper

```
def sort_highlight(col)
  "highlight" if params[:sort] == col
end
```

#### view

```
%th{class: sort_highlight('grade')}
```